# Trying to set Max and Min value of RangeValidator programatically in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to set Max and Min value of RangeValidator programatically as below:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RangeValidator" 
MaximumValue="<%# Max %>" MinimumValue="<%# Min %>" Type="Integer" > 
Value should be in <%# Min %> and <%# Max %> </asp:RangeValidator>
```

Here, Min and Max are integer from code behind. However getting error:
"The value '' of the MaximumValue property of 'RangeValidator1' cannot be converted to type 'Integer'."
I will really appreciate any help in this regard. Thanks

Comment: Try converting Max and Min to Integer explicitly in your RangeValidator binding.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
 <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server"ErrorMessage="RangeValidator"></asp:RangeValidator>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code For Codebehind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = 1.ToString();
            RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = 5.ToString();
        }
```

above code helps you to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

Following is complete syntax for RangeValidator.

```
<asp:RangeValidator 
         id="ProgrammaticID" 
         ControlToValidate="ProgrammaticID of control to validate" 
         MinimumValue="value"
         MaximumValue="value" 
         Type="DataType" 
         ErrorMessage="Message to display in ValidationSummary control"
         Text="Message to display in control"
         ForeColor="value" 
         BackColor="value"  
         runat="server" >
    </asp:RangeValidator>
```

**Note**The RangeValidator control throws an exception if the value specified by the MaximumValue or MinimumValue property cannot be converted to the data type specified by the Type property. [MSDN Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

So try setting *Type* attribute properly or change the *Max* and *Min* Value to appropriate type. In your case try converting *Min* and *Max* to Integer.